# Listening to UDP broadcast with AP enabled on android

Tags: android, udp, wifi

The scenario is there are two Android phones A and B. Phone A has AP enabled with a thread listening on UDP port 1234. Phone B connects to Phone A via Wifi and sends broadcast messages out on port 1234. Will Phone A receive these packets?

I know this is what Wifi Direct is for but the scenario involves an AP.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone else wants to do this, I tried it on two phones and the answer is yes :)